# Ensure the version of Node.js used at install time matches that used at runtime

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, compiler-errors

I am new to ionic.
I am trying to add cordova platform in my app

```
ionic cordova platform add android
```

when i execute the command error occurs:

> [cordova-res] Something went wrong installing the "sharp" module
>   [cordova-res] The module '\?\C:\Users\Varni2\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova-res\node_modules\sharp\build\Release\sharp.node'
>   [cordova-res] was compiled against a different Node.js version using
>   [cordova-res] NODE_MODULE_VERSION 64. This version of Node.js requires
>   [cordova-res] NODE_MODULE_VERSION 72. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
>   [cordova-res] the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`).
>   [cordova-res]  - Ensure the
>   version of Node.js used at install time matches that used at runtime
>   [cordova-res] - Consult the installation documentation at
>   https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/en/stable/install/
>   [cordova-res] -
>   Search for this error at https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues

It perfectly works when i execute

```
ionic cordova run android
```

it perfectly runs in emulator but when i change the code and execute below command same error occur.

```
cordova platform update android
```

Comment: delete your `node_modules` folder and run `npm install` take backup before this.

Comment: i tried but it did not work @NajamUsSaqib

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i had the same error, i fixed it by reinstalling the cordova-res :
npm install -g cordova-res